# nhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'call'

Tags: json, dart

I am facing an issue when data is fetched from the api and is not mapped into the model and the following error is thrown I have also posted the BodyModel class which contains the `fromJson` function:

```dart
Future<BodyModel> fetchJson(http.Client client, String? id) async {
  final response = await client.get(
    Uri.parse(uri2),
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    String jsonData = response.body;

    print(response.body);
    //print(jsonEncode(response.body));

    BodyModel alpha = responseJSON(jsonData);
    //print(alpha.toSet());
    //bravo = alpha;
    return alpha;
  } else {
    throw Exception('We were not able to successfully download the json data.');
  }
}

BodyModel responseJSON(String response) {
  final parse = jsonDecode(response);

  print(parse.toString());

  final resp = parse<BodyModel>((json) => BodyModel.fromJson(json));
  print(resp);
  return resp;
}
```

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BodyModel {
  String body;
  String title;

  BodyModel({
    required this.body,
    required this.title,
  });

  factory BodyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) {
    return BodyModel(
      body: jsonData['body'].toString(),
      title: jsonData['title'].toString(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to call the variable `parse`, like a method, which is not going to work since it is a `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Comment: Please show us your `BodyModel` class.

Comment: I have also tried it otherwise  like this: final parse = jsonDecode(response).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>() and the this final resp =
      parse.map<BodyModel>((json) => BodyModel.fromJson(json)).toList(); but got a similar kind of error

Comment: Instead of you just guessing what might work, maybe you should try read this part of the documentation: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json

Comment: that still doesn't help solving the above issue as I have used the documentation to code my BodeModel

Comment: Please show an example of how your JSON input looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `parse<BodyModel>(...)`.
It's not clear what you think that's supposed to do, but `parse` is a variable containing a `Map<String, dynamic>`, not a generic function.
It has type `dynamic`, so you won't get any warnings when misusing it.
Consider declaring parse as

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> parse = jsonDecode(response);
```

so it has the correct type.

From the return type of `responseJSON`, my guess is that you want to do:

```dart
final resp = BodyModel.fromJson(parse);
```

Comment: Thanks this solved my issue when I implemented it